# input text doesn't save value on pressing enter

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

I have a text field where the user is supposed to enter an address. On clicking the search button, a function is executed which uses the address to find POIs close by.  This is working well. However, when the user hits the return key, the value of the text field is not saved in the variable. This leads to the search being excecuted with the old value for the address variable.

I don't even understand why it makes it difference at all, to be honest.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" class="innenfeld" id="addressInput" name="addressInput">
<input type="button" class="send" onclick="newsearch()"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   function newsearch() {
     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
       } else {
         alert(address + ' not found');
       }
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> is submitting the form. You'll need to add an `onsubmit` event which calls your function (the return false prevents it from actually leaving the page)

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="newsearch(); return false">
```

Comment: This way, his button could be written with type `submit` and without `onclick` event like `<input type="submit" class="send" />`